# Why in SGX enclave string argument has to be used with [in] attribute

Tags: c, sgx, enclave

Using OCALL, I want to get a copy of C string that is dynamically created in untrusted memory into my enclave. Thus, I have to use `[out, string]` attribute.

However, I cannot do that because I have to add `[in]` attribute as well. The problem is that I really don't know the size of string and I don't want an overhead (that comes with `[in]`) from unnecessary copying of string from enclave to untrusted memory every time I make OCALL.

My edl file:

```
enclave {
    trusted {
        public void ecall_open(void);
    };
    untrusted {
        void ocall_get_string([out, string] char* str);
    };
};
```

`error: string/wstring/sizefunc should be used with an 'in' attribute`

Why do I have to add `[in]` attribute?

Is there a way to avoid this overhead?

Comment: The developer manual says "`string` and `wstring` cannot
be used with `out` alone." Perhaps you can have your OCALL using itself an ECALL to send the data into the enclave, something like: `ocall_get_string() allow ecall_to_pass_string([in, string] char *str)`. In the manual, this is written in Page 59 with title *Granting Access to ECALLs*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, one solution would be to pass a pointer to `char*` with `[out]` attribute and length:

`void ocall_get_string([out] char** str, [out] size_t* length);`

And then manually copy C string from untrusted memory to trusted using `memcpy()`.

Inside enclave:

```
char* untrusted_str; // pointer to string in untrusted memory that we would get form OCALL
size_t length;  // length of string

ocall_get_string(&untrusted_str, &length);

char *trusted_str = new char[length]; // pointer to string in trusted memory 
memcpy(trusted_str, untrusted_str, length);

// delete it later
delete[] trusted_str;
```

Comment: seems like a very bad practice. you trust an untrusted length and untrusted pointer. what if an attacker will pass you a pointer to your own secrets inside the enclave?

Comment: @Tal, agree, but I can call `sgx_is_outside_enclave()` to check whether my string is strictly outside the enclave, right?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel , decide what you want performance or security.

Comment: I simply want `[out, string]`,  and I don't understand why I have to include `in` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

`void ocall_get_string([out, size=sz] char* str, size_t sz);`

`size=sz` means the size of the `str` that will be copied back to Enclave automatically. If you don't specify size, then only one char will be copied back to Enclave.